# Concurrently playing one stream on device and other through AirPlay?

Tags: objective-c, airplay

I'm working on an iOS App where you can play multiple streams at the same time.Each stream use one AVPlayer. I have now added a MPVolumeView for AirPlay Support. My first issue is that when I AirPlay one stream, all streams on the device goes black. Is there any way of avoiding this? Is there possibilities to implement AirPlay at a lower lever to get better controll on how the local UI reacts?

/Björn

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: Setting _player.allowsExternalPlayback to NO disqualifies the player for AirPlay so the video will continue to play on the device eventhough AirPlay is active for another player. The MPVolumeView icon will still be active, so you need to remove it manually.

/BE